# "pip install pyarrow" returns syntax error

Tags: command-line, syntax

i already try to use linux cod on python.with importcommand.whats your idea to improve .do I use .os to import? how do i use it to install pyarrow in python.how can I install it atlink like windows ?
    import sys

> > > pip install pyarrow
> > >             File "", line 1
> > >               pip install pyarrow
> > >                         ^
> > >           SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: `pip` should be called from the “main” shell (Bash etc.), not from the Python shell which is indicated by `>>>`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are adding that at the wrong location.

On the python command line you use pyarrow by doing this:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import pyarrow
```

If you get ...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named pyarrow
```

you can use pip to install it from the linux command line so do a

```
>>> exit()
```

if you are still using that and on the $ do a ...

```
$ pip install pyarrow
```

and it will install it. If you also get a `/bin/sh: pip: not found` you will also need to 1st install pip with apt...

```
sudo easy_install pip
```

Comment: lenovo@Lenovo-Y50:~$ pip install pyarrow

Requirement already satisfied: pyarrow in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (0.9.0)

Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.0.0 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from 

pyarrow) (1.11.0)

Requirement already satisfied: futures in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyarrow) (3.2.0)

Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.10 in ./lib/python2.7/site-packages (from pyarrow) (1.15.0)

>>> import pyarrow
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyarrow'

Comment: python: can't open file 'setup.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
befor do this i try to check my python setup and I had this error

Comment: as matter of fact i cant find the reall problem on my system.since the time on my laptop switched windws and linux i cant find the reall way to sove the error

Comment: Command "/usr/bin/python3.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-install-l1c30aqp/pyarrow/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /tmp/pip-record-3wjby4o6/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-l1c30aqp/pyarrow/